# Issue with checkbox on zend framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element

I have an issue with a checkbox: it does not update to the database.

```
$emailnotification = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('emailnotification ', 'emailnotification', array(
    'checkedValue'  => 1,
    'uncheckedValue' => 0,
) );
$emailnotification->setLabel('emailnotification');
$emailnotification->setValue(1);
$this->addElement($emailnotification);
```

and on Controller I have action update the following code below for update:

```
if($this->_request->isPost())
{
    $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if($form->isValid($formData))
    {
        $contact = new Admin_Model_DbTable_Contact();
        $data = array();
        $data['idContact']            = $idContact;
        $data['firstname']            = $form->getValue('firstname');
        $data['lastname']             = $form->getValue('lastname');
        $data['emailnotification']    = $form->getValue('emailnotification');
        if($contact->editContact($data))
        {
            echo json_encode(array(
                "response"   => true,
                "message"    => "Contact " . $data['firstname'] . " " . $data['lastname'] . "a été modifié"
            ));
            exit();
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array(
                "response"     => false,
                "errorMessage" => "Il y a eu une erreur dans l'edition de Contact."
            ) );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

function editcontact:

```
public function editContact(array $data) { if(!empty($data)) { if($this->update($data, array('idContact = ?' => $data['idContact'])) > 0 ) { return true; } return false; } return false; }
```

on .phtml

```
$('#editContact').submit(function(event)
{
    var formId = $(this).attr('id');
    // Stop full page load
    event.preventDefault();

    //Request
    var data = {
        // contact's properties 
        firstname               :       $("#firstname").val(),
        lastname                :       $("#lastname").val(),
        emailnotification       :       $("#emailnotification").val(),
        batnotification         :       $("#batnotification").val()

    };  

    // Send
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#'+formId).attr('action'),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
        {                    
            if (data.response == true)
            {
                alert(data.message);
                //upContent('userManagement/index/','');



            }
            else
            { 
                alert(data.message);
            }
```

and not worked for me always message Undefined and not update the data base

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the code in your controller? And the entire form? And where is the script that saves the value from the form into the database?

Comment: $data['emailnotification']      = $form->getValue('emailnotification');

Comment: can you see in my code thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the method `editContact` in `Admin_Model_DbTable_Contact`?

Comment: public function editContact(array $data)
 {
  if(!empty($data))
  {
   if($this->update($data, array('idContact = ?' => $data['idContact'])) > 0 )
   {
    return true;
   }
   return false;
  }
  return false;
 }

Comment: Please add the code to your post instead of a comment.

Comment: Can you format your code? Also there seems to be a lot missing from the last code snippet.

Comment: when i click update i have message undefined and not do update

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues with your code and saving the data can be simplified so I'm giving you an example of how I'd set up the `editContact` method. Validation should obviously be done in the form itself. Keep in mind that database table and field names are probably different from your environment.

```
// Admin_Model_DbTable_Contact
public function editContact( array $data )
{
    Zend_Registry::get( 'db' )->update(
        'contact_table',
        $data,
        'contact_id = ' . intval( $data['idContact']
    );
    return Zend_Registry::get( 'db' )->lastInsertId();
}
```

You can also optimize your controller code a little:

```
// In controller action
if($this->_request->isPost() && $form->isValid( $formData ) )
{
    $contact = new Admin_Model_DbTable_Contact();
    if( $contact->editContact( $form->getValues() + array( 'idContact' => $idContact ) ) ) {
    {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "response"   => true,
            "message"    => "Contact {$form->getValue( 'firstname' )} {$form->getValue( 'lastname' )} a été modifié"
        ) );
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "response"     => false,
            "errorMessage" => "Il y a eu une erreur dans l'edition de Contact."
        ) );
    }
    exit();
}
```